# Help on using paperclip plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I've just installed this plugin, created the migrations, added everything I needed to make it work(I didn't install ImageMagick yet).

The problem is when I get the upload control parameter to save it in my controller, I get something like this:

```
#<File:C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Temp\RackMultipart.2560.6677>
```

instead of a simple string, like

> C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Temp\RackMultipart.2560.6677

And if I try to read it I get the following exception:

> TypeError  backtrace must be Array of
>   String

What am I doing wrong? How do I read it or simply get rid of the # and <> symbols?

Comment: Well I tried params[:profile][:photo].path and I'm getting the string, but not the image uploaded(saved on the db).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paperclip defaults to storing uploads in the file system, not the database. Uploads are stored in the public/system directory. Have you checked there?

Robin

Comment: I've changed something and now its saving to the db, but it won't work with styles. I've installed ImageMagick for windows(I've got Windows 7) and when I try to save some photo, having added before this line on the model(right after has_attached_file) :styles => {:thumb=> "100x100#",:small  => "150x150>"} it just fails saying " TypeError in ProfilesController#update

backtrace must be Array of String" Why is that?

Comment: Oh, and I think ImageMagick is installed correctly because I tried executing the command prompt commands to test it(I followed a tutorial) and all went fine.